# Autoselect Certificate for Chrome

Tags: automation, chromium, x509certificate, raspbian

Hello and thanks for help in advance!

I try to configure a Raspberry in Kiosk-Mode to show some website.

Problem: the [AutoSelectCertificateForUrls](https://chromeenterprise.google/policies/?policy=AutoSelectCertificateForUrls) doesn't work, because if I open chrome://policy the policy has no value set.

My .json file, placed under etc/chromium/policies/managed/auto_select_certificate.json

```
{
  "AutoSelectCertificateForUrls": [
    "{\"pattern\":\"https://adress.adress/somewhere\",\"filter\":{\"ISSUER\":{\"CN\":\"issuer.CN\“}}}“
  ]
}
```

Also tried

```
[
    "{\"pattern\":\"https://adress.adress\",\"filter\":{}}"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Because I just didn't got it to work, I tried a different approach.

In my case (Kiosk Mode) I don't need anything other than a one-time klick on "OK" (selecting the certificate). So I used xdotool to realize that.

1. sudo apt-get install xdotool -y
2. Create a script containing

   #!/bin/sh

   export DISPLAY=":0"

   export XAUTHORITY="/home/pi/.Xauthority"

   sleep 30    # To make sure the window is really loaded

   xdotool getactivewindow

   xdotool key KP_Enter
3. Make the script executable via "sudo chmod +x /etc/chromium/select_certificate"
4. **Before "exit 0"!** Append "/etc/chromium/select_certificate &" to "/etc/rc.local" to execute it every startup